# Center fixed width divs that sit next to each other?

Tags: html, alignment

I am trying to create a responsive template to be viewed on mobile/desktop. I have 'buttons' that I have created with divs that are floating left to sit side by side each other. I want them to centered because there may be 3 buttons, or 5 buttons or 6 buttons. I want all the buttons to look the same but if there are more buttons to flow down to the next line.

Like so:

-button 1-button-2-button-3-button-4

--------- button 6-button 7 --------

so i don't want to use relative div widths but have it dynamic so that if viewed on a mobile phone it may show

-button 1-

-button 2-

-button 3-

the width container has to be max 80% as that is my template and i want to line it up with an image.

i currently have:

```css
#container {
margin-left: 10% ;
margin-right: 10%;
width: 80%
}

.buttonbg {
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: normal;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-size: 24px;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
padding: 10px 14px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 2px;
float: left;
width: 20%;
min-width: 165px;
}

a.button {
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: normal;
text-decoration: none;
}


#button1 { background-color: rgba(255, 204, 204,1); }
#button2 { background-color: rgba(255, 153, 153,1); }
#button3 { background-color: rgba(255, 163, 194,1); }
#button4 { background-color: rgba(255, 204, 153,1); }
#button5 { background-color: rgba(255, 245, 245,1); }
#button6 { background-color: rgba(255, 245, 245,1); }

.buttonbg:hover {
background-color: #cccccc !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="buttonbg" id="button1"><a class="button"
href="http://client.samanthaongphoto.com/farahandsean" target="_blank"
alt="Farah &amp; Sean's Wedding Photos by Samantha Ong Photography">Wedding<br>
Gallery</a></div>
<div class="buttonbg" id="button2"><a class="button" href="slideshow/"
target="_blank"
alt="Farah &amp; Sean's Wedding Slideshow by Samantha Ong Photography">Wedding<br>
Slideshow</a></div>
<div class="buttonbg" id="button3"><a class="button" href="slideshow/"
target="_blank"
alt="Farah &amp; Sean's Wedding Slideshow by Samantha Ong Photography">Wedding<br>
Slideshow</a></div>
<div class="buttonbg" id="button4"><a class="button" href="slideshow/"
target="_blank"
alt="Farah &amp; Sean's Wedding Slideshow by Samantha Ong Photography">Wedding<br>
Slideshow</a></div>
<div class="buttonbg" id="button5"><a class="button" href="slideshow/"
target="_blank"
alt="Farah &amp; Sean's Wedding Slideshow by Samantha Ong Photography">Wedding<br>
Slideshow</a></div>
</div>
```

as you can see, the buttons are aligning left. can anyone help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MOBILE-CSS(Phones)

> link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mobile.css"
>          media="only screen and (max-device-width: 490px)"

- that is for mobile devices
- you call an other CSS file for Desktop with

DESKTOP-CSS(PC)

> link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mobile.css"
>          media="only screen and (min-device-width: 491px)"

- That technic is called CSS medi-queries, it's used to create responsive web-pages.
- You must write your CSS code in another file and call it as i showed you upper.( only one CSS file - two html  element on the head)